# Как переименовать файл с помощью python?

Tags: python

Код:

```
 paths = "/content/train2017"
 midis = os.listdir(paths)
    for j in midis: 
        for i in imgsids:
            os.renames("/content/train2017/" + j, str(i) + ".jpg")
```

Код ошибки:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-b57cb06c2dff> in <module>()
     14 for j in midis:
     15     for i in imgsids:
---> 16         os.renames("/content/train2017/" + j, str(i) + ".jpg")
     17 catIds = coco.getCatIds(catNms=['person', "car"])
     18 imgIds = coco.getImgIds(catIds=catIds );

/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py in renames(old, new)
    268     if head and tail and not path.exists(head):
    269         makedirs(head)
--> 270     rename(old, new)
    271     head, tail = path.split(old)
    272     if head and tail:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/train2017/000000211351.jpg' -> '522418.jpg'
```

Проблема в том, что файл есть, но ни через "os", ни через "pathlib", мне выдают эту ошибку.

Фото директории:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может быть это:

```
os.renames("/content/train2017/" + j, "/content/train2017/" +  str(i) + ".jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.rename('file1','file2')
#or
os.system('mv file1 file2')
```

к вопросу об относительных и абсолютных путях: если в начале стоит c:/ (для винды) или / (просто слеш для линукс или сервера) то путь абсолютный и он считается от корня диска, если имя начинается с буквы то путь относительный и его путь начинается с текущей папки. То есть вышеприведённый код подходит для переименования файла в той же папке что и скрипт.